# Magento2 images in CMS block

Tags: magento-2.1, image, cms-block

I have an image in:

```
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/milano/web/images/natale/IMG_7300.JPG
```

How can I refer to this image in CMS block? I know I should use:

```
<img src="{{media url="..."}}" alt="" />
```

What shall I put instead of `"..."` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Use Of **`{{view url=""}}`**

You have to use **view url** like below for all images are coming from theme folder,

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/web/images/

```
{{view url="images/natale/IMG_7300.JPG"}}
```

You can use in your static block or page using below way,

> `<img src="{{view url="images/natale/IMG_7300.JPG"}}" alt="" />`

2. Use Of **`{{media url=""}}`**

For All images That are coming from `pub/media` folder,

path like, **pub/media/customfolder/imagename.jpg at that time use media url.**

You have to use `{{media url="customfolder/imagename.jpg"}}`

> `<img src="{{media url="customfolder/imagename.jpg"}}" alt="" />`

Comment: to add an explanation `{{media}}` directive works only for assets located in the media folder.

Comment: @Marius, ok sure, i will explain in more. Thanks.

Comment: @Marius, I have updated my answer.