# Magento 2 WYSIWYG Media image url missing

Tags: product, magento-2.1

I have inserted image in product description using this code

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/gmp.jpg"}}" alt="" />
```

after insert completed i saved it. thats's fine working good.

After saving done I clicked showhide editor but is showing

```
    <img src="{{media url="
```

showing this simple code only please any one know help me how to fix

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
<img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/gmp.jpg'}}" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Single quoted** strings will display things almost completely "as is." Variables and most escape sequences will not be interpreted. The exception is that to display a literal single quote, you can escape it with a back slash \', and to display a back slash, you can escape it with another backslash \ (So yes, even single quoted strings are parsed).
>
> **Double quote** strings will display a host of escaped characters (including some regexes), and variables in the strings will be evaluated. An important point here is that you can use curly braces to isolate the name of the variable you want evaluated. For example let's say you have the variable $type and you what to echo "The $types are" That will look for the variable $types. To get around this use echo "The {$type}s are" You can put the left brace before or after the dollar sign.

Try this -

```
<img src="{{media url='[fodername]/imagefilename.jpg'}}" alt="" />
```

***Note:- Images are store in /pub/media or in your Created Theme Folder***

app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/{themme_name}/Magento_Theme/web/images/All images

OR

app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/{themme_name}/web/images/All images

[click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150038/magento2-images-in-cms-block)  or [Here Also](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-urls-dynamic-media.html)

***I Hope This Helps You.***